# Is it possible to do these loops with parallel streams?

Tags: java, loops, optimization, concurrency, java-stream

If i have this code that executes in a nested loop

```
int height = ...;
int width = ...;
int sourceIncrement = ...;
int destIncrement = ...;
int sourceOffset = ...;
int destOffset = ...;
int  sourceArray[] = ...;
byte destArray[] = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {                              
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {               
        int pixel = sourceArray[sourceOffset ++];           
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel      );
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >>  8);
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >> 16);
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >> 24);
    }                                           
    sourceOffset += sourceIncrement;                      
    destOffset += destIncrement;                     
}
```

and i want to make it run in parallel I will try to do it with streams

```
IntStream.range(0, height).parallel().forEach(y -> {    
    IntStream.range(0, width).parallel().forEach(x -> {
        int pixel = sourceArray[sourceOffset ++];              
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel      );   
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >>  8);   
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >> 16);   
        destArray[destOffset ++] = (byte) (pixel >> 24);   
    });                                            
    sourceOffset += sourceIncrement;                         
    destOffset += destIncrement;                        
});
```

but it is wrong because the offsets will increment before the code that depends on them will ran.  Is it actually possible to make it run in parallel correctly?

Comment: Calculate `destOffset` and `sourceOffset` for each iteration of the inner loop. It looks simply to be `sourceOffset = (i + sourceIncrement) * height + j`, for example.

Comment: @AndyTurner then i could parallelize the outer loop right? What about the inner loop?

Comment: If you manage the offset calculation, there is no need for two loops.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t perform manual copying.

You can use, e.g.

```
IntBuffer src = IntBuffer.wrap(sourceArray, sourceOffset, sourceArray.length-sourceOffset);
IntBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(destArray, destOffset, destArray.length - destOffset)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    dst.put(src.limit(src.position()+width));
    src.limit(src.capacity()).position(src.position() + sourceIncrement);
    dst.position(dst.position() + (destIncrement >> 2));
}
```

This assumes that `destIncrement` is describing pixel units, i.e. is a multiple of four. Further, it assumes that the arrays are long enough that there is `sourceIncrement` resp. `destIncrement` room for the last row, which isn’t written, but the buffer doesn’t allow setting the position after the last row otherwise.

If the arrays don’t have that room, you’d have to exit the loop in the last row, before incrementing the positions:

```
if(height > 0) {
    IntBuffer src = IntBuffer.wrap(sourceArray, sourceOffset,
                                                sourceArray.length - sourceOffset);
    IntBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(destArray, destOffset, destArray.length - destOffset)
            .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; ;) {
        dst.put(src.limit(src.position()+width));
        if(++i == height) break;
        src.limit(src.capacity()).position(src.position() + sourceIncrement);
        dst.position(dst.position() + (destIncrement >> 2));
    }
}
```

It’s not clear whether this would benefit from parallel processing at all, but for completion, here’s a parallel variant:

```
IntBuffer src = IntBuffer.wrap(sourceArray, sourceOffset, (width+sourceIncrement)*height);
IntBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(destArray, destOffset, (width*4+destIncrement)*height)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();

int srcRow = width + sourceIncrement, dstRow = width + (destIncrement>>2);
IntStream.range(0, height).parallel()
    .forEach(y -> dst.slice().position(y * dstRow)
        .put(src.slice().position(y * srcRow).limit(y * srcRow + width))
    );
```

Since the position and limit of a buffer aren’t thread safe, we have to create a local buffer. This solution uses `slice()` which encapsulates the initial values of `sourceOffset` resp. `destOffset`, simplifying the calculation of position and limit for the transfer operation. Calculating them before the transfer also ensures that the position is never advanced farther than the `width` of the last row.